# Make bot disconnect if it's alone in a voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to disconnect the bot if it's alone on a voice channel? Is there any event that triggers each time a person leaves the vc or something similar that would do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the voice channels well but you can check the member count with [VoiceChannel.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members) and make a task loop like

```
async def check():
    # define the voice channel
    member_count = len(voice_channel.members)
    if member_count == 1:
        # leave the channel
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
client.loop.create_task(check())
```

There might be better answers but this can also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To someone who might be having the same issue and want an answer

```
GUILD_VC_TIMER = {}
# this event runs when user leave / join / defen / mute 
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # if event is triggered by the bot? return
    if member.id == bot.user.id:
        return

    # when before.channel != None that means user has left a channel
    if before.channel != None:
        voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients , channel__guild__id = before.channel.guild.id)

        # voice is voiceClient and if it's none? that means the bot is not in an y VC of the Guild that triggerd this event 
        if voice == None:
            return

        # if VC left by the user is not equal to the VC that bot is in? then return
        if voice.channel.id != before.channel.id:
            return

        # if VC has only 1 member (including the bot)
        if len(voice.channel.members) <= 1:

            GUILD_VC_TIMER[before.channel.guild.id] = 0

            while True:
                print("Time" , str(GUILD_VC_TIMER[before.channel.guild.id]) , "Total Members" , str(len(voice.channel.members)))

                await asyncio.sleep(1)

                GUILD_VC_TIMER[before.channel.guild.id] += 1
                
                # if vc has more than 1 member or bot is already disconnectd ? break
                if len(voice.channel.members) >= 2 or not voice.is_connected():
                    break

                # if bot has been alone in the VC for more than 60 seconds ? disconnect
                if GUILD_VC_TIMER[before.channel.guild.id] >= 60:
                    await voice.disconnect()
                    return
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me the trouble to write so much code. Works perfectly!