# How to disconnect a discord bot from voice channel after user left?

Tags: asynchronous, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I would like to add an event that my music bot leaves the voice channel immediately if the user leaves while the song is still playing. If there are multiple users in the channel, the bot should of course stay in the channel. I only have one approach there, but would need help. I would try the following:

```py
async def check_member(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    member_count = len(voice_channel.members)
    if member_count == 1:
        await channel.disconnect
```

but somehow this doesn't seem to work.
I know for fact that there is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63657643/make-bot-disconnect-if-its-alone-in-a-voice-channel-discord-py) but this did not work for me too as I defined some things different.

My second attempt was:

```py
    async def check_member(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        member_count = len(channel.members)
        client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        if member_count == 1:
            await client.disconnect()
```

(Did not work either.)

To define `does not work`: I build the function in a different way now:

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=2)
    async def check(self, ctx):
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        member_count = len(voice_channel.members)
        client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        if member_count == 1:
            await client.disconnect()
```

This is now a total different count. What I am trying to do is loop the `commands.Cog.listener()` function every 2 seconds. For tests I played a song and left instantly after the bot started playing. I thought the bot would leave the channel too but it did not. There was no output in my log that I defined something wrong.

Comment: Describe "doesn't work"? Errors? Weird behaviour? Also, can you add more relevant code such as how you're using this function?

Comment: @stijndcl Edited the post. To sum it up: No errors but also the bot is not leaving the channel.

Comment: How are you filling in the `ctx` parameter? It's a task, there is no invocation context like for commands, Discord won't fill that in by default (because it doesn't exist). Also, you're not getting any errors because you're using a task, which doesn't show errors by default. Tasks require custom error handlers.

Comment: He's probably passing the `ctx` parameter in `Task.start(*args)`. Also your code doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is kinda unefficient, you can simply use the `on_voice_state_update` event

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    voice_state = member.guild.voice_client
    # Checking if the bot is connected to a channel and if there is only 1 member connected to it (the bot itself)
    if voice_state is not None and len(voice_state.channel.members) == 1:
        # You should also check if the song is still playing
        await voice_state.disconnect()
```

Reference:

- [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_sta#discord.on_voice_state_update)

Comment: So I also added a method to check if the bot is playing any audio and also implemented that. However the bot still does not disconnect. For what do we need `before, after` here?
`

Comment: Sorry, you should compare to 1 member (the bot itself) not 0.  Before and after are the voice states prior and before of the change

Comment: Do I need to import intents for that? I do not see a single error but even after importing the needed intents the bot is on strike again. I have the following [checks](http://prntscr.com/wjaifz). Do I maybe need to built in the checks to `on_voice_state_update` itself or put the function into the `Music` class? I don't know if that effects that.

Comment: You need to enable `intents.members`, `intents.guilds` and `intents.voice_states` - default intents + `intents.members` will also work

Comment: Yes, I read an article about that. After importing the [intents](http://prntscr.com/wjao1c) and starting it correctly it does not look like that the bot likes me because he is not disconnecting after I left the channel. I set up a [video](https://youtu.be/Z6f5an9UP-Q)  for you where you can maybe see why it is not working, let me know if you can't find the mistake either. (Maybe it is because of my different usage with the oder methods?)

Comment: Hm that's really weird, I tried the code and it works flawlessly for me, (video [here](https://streamable.com/tn2hjc)) maybe you forgot to import PyNaCl?

Comment: I see, could it be because of a different usage? You use `bot.event` but I would use `commands.Cog.listener`. I also imported PyNaCl in my req. file which starts/installs all the modules mentioned there.

Comment: it also works with `commands.Cog.listener`, I'm not sure why is not working for you

Comment: `commands.Cog.listener` gives out the following: [1](http://prntscr.com/wjbsug) and [2](http://prntscr.com/wjbsxi) - Removed discussion from chat so others can see it too.

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself, You didn't add the self, before and after arguments. Problem is that you didn't copy the code correctly

Comment: Forgot that indeed, so all it needed was "self" and the other arguments. Sorry for wasting time and thanks for your help!